# Get a loop work

Tags: c, loops, pointers, printf

I found this C example on a website and are trying to get it work:

```
void simple(int n, float *a, float *b)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (a[i] + a[i-1]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

This is what I added just for testing purposes:

```
int main()
{
    float *p1, *p2, a, b;
    a = 5;
    b = 10;

    p1 = &a;
    p2 = &b;

    simple(5, p1, p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it ok?

But how can I see what this example produces? Can I add a `printf` into the loop? If so, what kind of parameters are needed?

Comment: Your p1 and p2 should point to float arrays and not simple float variables.

Comment: A quick look on the code shows that `a` and `b` should be arrays, and `n` would be the length of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your example is not ok, you are using 5 elements in an object that only contains 1. Use something like

```
float a[5] = { 2, 3 ,4, 5, 6 };
```

to obtain real arrays to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
void simple(int n, float *a, float *b)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (a[i] + a[i - 1]) / 2.0;

        printf("For i = %d:\n", i);
        printf("\ta[i] = %.2f\n", a[i]);
        printf("\tb[i] = %.2f\n\n", b[i]);
    }
}
```